# Why don't working NoWrap of Label in xamarin.form?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, text, label, nowrap

I am trying to show full text in label.
so I add Nowrap in LineBreakMode but full text don't show.

```
<widgets:CustomLabel ContentKey="{Binding TotalAmount, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource NormalLabelStyle}"
                                 TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryBlueColor}"
                                 Margin="{StaticResource TinyMarginTop}"
                                 LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                 MaxLines="1"
                                 HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
```

[image]

Text is $0.16.
if I change MaxLines to 2, here
[image]

If I show text in one line, How should I fix it?

Comment: You need to make the label wide enough to fit your text.  NoWrap will not be useful if the label is too small

Comment: what do you mean? Should I add width of label?

Comment: Show definition of CustomLabel class. That custom component probably has a default width that is too small. WidthRequest property might help. Or Jessie’s answer. It also depends on definition of CustomLabel.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve  I added WidthRequest, but it does not changed

Comment: Hi @BohdanV.  could you please post the code of your `CustomLabel ` and the layout of above screenshot you shared ?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you shared, we can find that you want to display the string in one line, so you can set the `MaxLines` to `1` and set the width of the Label wide enough to wrap the string.

Of course, you can also set the `HorizontalOptions` to fill the width of the parent view.

For example:

```
    <Label x:Name="mLabel" Text="abccccccccccccc" MaxLines="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```